# How to convert jpg image to proper blob data type using php

Tags: php, blob, fread

```
<?php
$file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$tmp_name  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'];

// The codes written above work fine and have proper information.

$fp = fopen($tmp_name, 'r'); // This one crashes.
$file_content = fread($fp, $file_size) or die("Error: cannot read file");
$file_content = mysql_real_escape_string($file_content) or die("Error: cannot read file");
fclose($fp);

....
```

I'm a newbie to PHP stuff. I'm trying to store a jpg image as blob in a database but terribly struggling with it :( I tried many tutorials and read documents but still no luck. Any suggestions or tutorials that might help me out..?

Comment: When your call to fopen crashes, what error is output? Try to use E_ALL | E_STRICT as your error reporting level to get more information.

Comment: Sorry but what would be the code like..? I have no idea how to use what you suggested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When opening binary files with `fopen()`, use the `rb` mode, ie

```
$fp = fopen($tmp_name, 'rb');
```

Alternatively, you may simply use `file_get_contents()`, eg

```
$file_content = file_get_contents($tmp_name);
```

To enable better error reporting, place this at the top of your script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!   $file_content = file_get_contents($tmp_name);  totally worked out.  and Error reporting tip is awesome. I never used it to debug. :D <3<3