# Inserting a file into database table in blob format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter framework and i am trying to upload **blob** content (an image in this case) into the database table

following is my controller code

```
public function usersubmit()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[8]|max_length[255]|trim|matches[passconf]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf','Password','required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Mobile No.','trim|less_than[10000000000]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pincode','Pincode','trim|numeric');
    /*$config['upload_path']='./files/images/profilepic/';
    $config['allowed_types']='gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']='16000';
    //$config['file_name']=''
    //$this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);*/

     if(!$this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
            $data['title']="Users";
            $data['page']="createuser";
            $this->load->view('main',data);
            return;
    }
    $content;

    $tmpname  = $_FILES['propic']['tmp_name']; //The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.
    $filesize = $_FILES['propic']['size'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['propic']['type'];
    $allowedtypes=array("image/jpeg","image/jpg","image/png","image/gif");
    if($filesize>=0){
        if(in_array($filetype, $allowedtypes))
        {
            $fp      = fopen($tmpname, 'r');
            $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname));
            $data['photo'] = addslashes($content);  //it adds blackslashes after each quote(double or single)
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

    //$fieldname='propic';

        $data['name']=  $this->input->post('name');
        $data['email']= $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']=$this->input->post('password');
        $data['phone']=$this->input->post('phone');
        $data['city']=$this->input->post('city');
        $data['pincode']=  $this->input->post('pincode');
        $data['dob']=$this->input->post('dob');
        $data['id']=NULL;
        $data['accesslevel']='2';
        $data['status']='1';
        $data['timestamp']=NULL;

    if($this->user_model->createuser($data))
    {
        $this->viewusers();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->createuser();
    }

    //$data
}
```

following is the model function used

```
public function createuser($user)
{
    $query=  $this->db->insert('user',$user);
    if($query)
        return TRUE;
    return false;
}
```

and the input form in the view

```
<form  role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('start/usersubmit') ;?>">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="propic" id="propic" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Everything here works correctly, except the file uploaded.
This file is uploaded into the database but is size is slightly higher than the actual one (about 5% more) and also the file gets corrupt. That is when I download it from the database, the file is not readable. I need to know whats the error with my code.

Comment: Your problem: `$data['photo'] = addslashes($content);` Why do you need to do that when the CI `insert()` method already escapes your data for you?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845233/how-to-convert-jpg-image-to-proper-blob-data-type-using-php advised to use `rb` as the `fopen` mode.

Comment: @sjagr ,without this there is absolutely no file uploaded, NULL value is shown in the database. See this http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Comment: That doesn't make sense, can you please output the value of `$content` after the `fread` line?

Comment: @Ofir Baruch, pardon me, it didn't give null but the things remained the same, i still get a corrupted file

Comment: Have you followed @sjagr advice as well?

Comment: yeah, that gave NULL value, I have mentioned it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68227/discussion-between-piyush-vishwakarma-and-ofir-baruch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the the discussion in the chat, this was the solution:

Replace the following code:

```
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname));
$data['photo'] = addslashes($content);  //it adds blackslashes after each quote(double or single)
```

With:

```
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname));
        $data['photo'] = $content;
```