# How to save image as blob (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, blob

I need to upload a blob file to the database for user registration, but I can't.

Doesn't upload the .jpg file correctly to the database. "Something" is uploaded but not the .jpg file :( If I upload the file directly from phpmyadmin, I can display it with this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ chunk_split(base64_encode(Auth::user()->img)) }}">
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="POST"action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Models/Users.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'img'
    ];
```

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->binary('img');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**RegistrerController.php**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'img' => $data['img']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `[...'img' => base64_encode($data['img'])...]`

Comment: something is update, but when I use this:
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ chunk_split(base64_encode(Auth::user()->img)) }}"> I only obtain: <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,TDNSdGNDOXdhSEEwUzBJNU1VWT0=
">

Comment: no image is displayed

Comment: But the blob was successfully save in the database?

Comment: a users-img.bin file has been created and inside the file this is displayed: L3RtcC9waHA0S0I5MUY=

Comment: your question was how to save blob. i think you store a blob, right? I understand you right, that now you have a next problem?

Comment: I need to store and show the image

Comment: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ base64_encode( Auth::user()->img ) }}"/>`

Comment: It doesn't work. It generates this html and it doesn't show the image:

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,TDNSdGNDOXdhSEEwUzBJNU1VWT0=">`

Comment: You still aren’t showing how you save this image to the database. Where is the code that saves the image?

Comment: All the code that I have in my Laravel project is the one that I write in the original post. I don't know if I need something to do

Comment: Your "register" route points to another method that is creating the `$data` array. That method is then calling the `RegisterController::create()` method you've shown here. `L3RtcC9waHA0S0I5MUY=` is `/tmp/php4KB91F` so you are saving the file name and not the file itself to the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert jpg image to proper blob data type using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845233/how-to-convert-jpg-image-to-proper-blob-data-type-using-php)